# About Schedule taks

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

As am new to the ML Datahubframework,exploring the functionalities and services provided by the datahubframework.

1. Has seen the gradle command to create service extensions and transforms.
2. Haven't seen any gradle command to create the schedule tasks and ext library commands for other services(ingest,job,api's) under ml-modules.
3. Trying to search in google for a long time but didnt find any info.Can someone help me with links.
4. Has seen mlscaffold command which creates the template project for all services but i want to create the services/functionalities step by step.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of available tasks by running `./gradlew tasks`. DHF is built using ml-gradle, which has [a wiki listing available tasks](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Task-reference). There is also documentation for DHF with [a list of tasks specific to DHF](https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/tools/gradle/gradle-tasks.html).

Comment: i have searched all the commands in the same page many times but haven't seen the gradle command for schedule task and extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduled tasks are deployed using [ml-gradle](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki), and are defined in [src/main/ml-config/tasks/](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/tree/master/examples/sample-project/src/main/ml-config/tasks).  The tasks can be defined in JSON or XML, and there is an example task there, as well as a [JSON example in the MarkLogic Docs](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/manage/v2/tasks).

There are also a number of other [examples available for MarkLogic configuration items](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/tree/master/examples) that are not specific to the Data Hub Framework, on the [ml-gradle github site](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki).